# Как собирать два различных билда приложения с помощью vue-cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Есть проект, в котором собираются два различных приложения. Структура такая:

```
my-app/
+- ...
+- dist/
|  +- 1proj/         1project bundle and files
|  +- 2proj/        2project bundle and files
+- public/
|  index.html
+- src/
|  +- components/    Shared components
|  +- apps/         
|      +- 1proj/        Entry point, router, store... for the 1proj app
|      +- 2proj/        Entry point, router, store... for the 2proj app
+- ...
| package.json
| vue.config.js
```

Для того чтобы собирались два разных приложения в билде прописал в package.json для скриптов данный код:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build:1proj": "vue-cli-service build --dest dist/1proj src/apps/1proj/index.ts",
    "build:2proj": "vue-cli-service build --dest dist/2proj src/apps/2proj/index.ts",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
  },
```

Так он все нормально собирает, как мне надо, но для разработки мне необходимо запускать npm run serve и работать с проектами

Чтобы можно было запускать npm run serve сразу двух разных приложений прописал в vue.config.js настройку для MPA

vue.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    publicPath: '.',

    pages: {
        '1proj': {
            entry: './src/apps/1proj/index.ts',
            template: 'public/index.html',
            title: '1proj'
        },
        '2proj': {
            entry: './src/apps/2proj/index.ts',
            template: 'public/index.html',
            title: '2proj'
        }
    },
};
```

Теперь спокойно могу при запуске локального сервера заходить на localhost:8080/proj1.html#/ или localhost:8080/proj2.html#/ и работать с двумя приложениями.

Но из-за этой настройки MPA во время сборки build начинают собираться проекты с двумя html файлами (proj1.html и proj2.html), а не как мне нужно - SPA(dist/proj1/proj1.html и dist/proj2/proj2.html). Как объяснить vue-cli, что я хочу использовать MPA только для разработки, во время запуска npm run serve, а билд делал только SPA два разных проекта?

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью проверки на режим разработки

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    publicPath: '.',

    pages: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? {
        '1proj': {
            entry: './src/apps/1proj/index.ts',
            template: 'public/index.html',
            title: '1proj'
        },
        '2proj': {
            entry: './src/apps/2proj/index.ts',
            template: 'public/index.html',
            title: '2proj'
        }
    } : undefined,
};
```

Но сомневаюсь, что это нормальное решение. Есть вопросы еще как задавать пути для различных статичных файлов при билде, которые берутся из папки public, например если нужно указать для статичного index.html другой title или поставить различные favicons

Comment: Есть похожий вопрос и [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1048435/287469). Почему считаете, что использовать окружения неправильно?